# $U(1)_A$ effects on the baryons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking, quantum-anomalies

We know that the axial $U(1)_A$ is anomalous thus not a global symmetry. Therefore there is no direct associated pseudo goldstone boson for $U(1)_A$. This makes the $\eta'$ much more massive than the other pseudo goldstone 8 mesons.

Do we have similar $U(1)_A$ effects on the baryons? If so, which baryon(s) is/are associated with  $U(1)_A$ thus more massive than the other baryons? (Also what are the other flavor symmetries should one look at $SU(N)_V$? or $SU(N)_A$? )

Answer (score 5):

You are really asking about *parity doubling of baryons*.

*Fixing language*: (*N* is a silly meretricious conflation of 2 and 3, since for *N* > 3 the quark masses completely invalidate any axial charge considerations, as per Gell-Mann's cynosure). For any multiplet except pseudoscalars, say, for baryons *B*,
$$
B \mapsto e^{i\theta_L^i T^i \frac{1-\gamma^5}{2} + i\theta_R^i T^i \frac{1+\gamma^5}{2}+ i\theta_V  +i\theta_A  \gamma^5   } B,
$$
where the diagonal subgroup is defined by $\theta_L^i=\theta_R^i$; the Nambu-Goldstone-mode axial by $\theta_L^i=-\theta_R^i$; the baryon number by $\theta_V$; and the anomalous axial U(1) by $\theta_A$. $SU(3)_V$ is the eightfold way, which works quite well put to quark mass differences. The symmetries of the 8 axial are well-understood to be SSB, as per the lightness of their associated pseudoscalars.

- Let me dispatch the canards first: The broken and unbroken generator charges with odd parity correspond one-to-one with pseudoscalar mesons with the *same* quantum numbers, parity and flavor, which are pseudogoldstone bosons (or not--for the axial U(1), your η'). There is *no such meaningful correspondence* between any other meson or baryon multiplets and these charges.
- In addition, the $N^2-1$ SSBroken axial generators are in a coset space, $\frac{SU(N)_L\times SU(N)_A}{SU(N)_V}$, and do *not* close to a Lie algebra (what you called $SU(N)_A$, a guaranteed trail of folly to  grim conceptual grief).

Since both the $N^2-1$ SSB axial charges and the hapless  anomalous violated axial U(1) charge would connect baryons of opposite parities  by dint of their $\gamma_5$, and the low-lying spectrum of baryons is not parity-doubled, early students of chiral symmetry appreciated it is SSBroken; and, for $U(1)_A$ anomaly-broken. This was a useful hint they gladly took.

***However***, quite ironically, for higher excitation baryons, there *is* ample experimental evidence of parity doubling, at masses of order 1.5–3 GeV, especially for non-strange ones, cf. the references cited, and especially section 2 of ref [1].

Most, notably refs [2,3], try to explain  this approximate doubling by partial/effective restoration of chiral symmetry at high temperatures or exotic low-temperature-high-density  environments, and connect to our familiar low-energy physics. Some type of dynamical decoupling from pseudoscalars is envisioned, suppressing axial-breaking operators.

> By this they mean that the symmetry is realized (approximately) in Wigner–Weyl mode with the appearance of (approximately) degenerate multiplets that transform into one another linearly under chiral rotations. [1]

- The first reference [1], however, is further exploring an *alternative, very different* possibility: namely, that the anomalous $U(1)_A$ violation is somehow, dynamically, suppressed/cancelled/inconsequential in the baryon sector, leading to (imperfect) parity doubling.

The symmetry is broken explicitly by instantons/gluons (a lot, as opposed to by the customary small violation due to quark masses in ChPT): $[H,Q_5]\neq 0$, but leaves a subspace where the spectrum is sparse, involving baryons, alone; thereby permitting partial degeneracy in parity doublets! (Focus on Table 1 of [1].)

It is a mysterious, dark, recondite possibility of "unknown unknowns",  worth exploring.

---

*References*

1. Jaffe, R. L., Pirjol, D., & Scardicchio, A. (2006). Parity doubling among the baryons. Physics reports, 435(6), 157-182.
2. Glozman, L. Y. (2010). Chiral symmetry restoration in excited hadrons and dense matter. Chinese Physics C, 34(9), 1212.
3. Cohen, T. D. (2009). Hadrons and chiral symmetry. Nuclear Physics B-Proceedings Supplements, 195, 59-92.
4. Sasaki, C. (2018). Parity doubling of baryons in a chiral approach with three flavors. Nuclear Physics A, 970, 388-397.

Comment: Thanks very much +1 --- I will accept your answer -- after I digest them (also other nice answers -- I will accept them but I need to digest first.)

Comment: I guess it didn't sink in.